# Laravel Model lists method return all the value of the column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

a model defined like this:

```
class Model extends Eloquent {
        protected $table='model';
    }
```

then I query like:

```
$model=Model::find(2);
$model->id;//return 2;
$model->lists('id');//return array contains all the ids in model table like ['1','2','3',...]. not ['2'];
```

so, I though the lists method should only contains  array which only has ids was found. why it has all the id of model table.

and which Class API in Laravel API doc I should look after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queries), the lists function fetches a list of column values for the table. Calling it in this manner is essentially running a brand new query.

Comment: it means:     Db::table('model')->find('2')->id;//=Model::find(2)->id; Db::table('model')->list('id');//=Model::find(2)->list('id');                am I right?

Comment: Well, you're not really using it as documented. The only mention of the `list` function is in conjunction with a `DB::table()` call. There's no mention of it whatsoever in the Eloquent docs. That it does anything is simply a side effect of how Eloquent sits in front of the database.

Comment: so DB class is behind Eloquent to operate the Database, am I right?

Comment: Yes, Eloquent's functions are making DB calls behind the scenes.